# Animação de carregamento ao enviar formulário

Tags: javascript, css3, formulário

Coloquei o plugin [Pace Master](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) em minha página que faz uma barra carregar na parte superior enquanto a página esta carregando, como a do YouTube, entretanto, quero fazer com que essa mesma barra carregue ao enviar o formulário que contém na página, caso ele esteja devidamente preenchido. Ja vi isso em uma infinidade de sites, e parece ser bem simples mas não tenho muito conhecimento em JavaScript ainda, por isso das formas que tentei não funcionou.  Tentei chamar a função do loading com onclick mas não funcionou, estava querendo que funcionasse no mínimo sem verificar se o form esta preenchido pois o principal seria que o usuário tivesse um feedback quando clicasse em enviar o form.

```
    <label for="questao5">5. Se possível, liste alguns sites que você gosta, incluindo as URLs.</label> 
    <textarea name="questao5" id="questao5" required></textarea> 
    <button class="btn" id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit">Enviar</button>

.pace {
-webkit-pointer-events: none;
pointer-events: none;

-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.pace-inactive {
display: none;
}
.pace .pace-progress {
background: #8BB006;
position: fixed;
z-index: 2000;
top: 0;
right: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
}
```

-JavaScript do plugin-
[Link GitHub](https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/blob/master/pace.js)

-JavaScript do formulário-

```
$('.formphp').on('submit', function() {
    var emailContato = "contato@contato.com.br"; // Escreva aqui o seu e-mail

    var that = $(this),
            url = that.attr('action'),
            type = that.attr('method'),
            data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {

            if( $('[name="leaveblank"]').val().length != 0 ) {
                $('.formphp').html("<div id='form-erro'></div>");
                $('#form-erro').html("<span>Falha no envio!</span><p>Você pode tentar novamente, ou enviar direto para o e-mail " + emailContato + " </p>")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                $('#form-erro');
                });
            } else {

                $('.formphp').html("<div id='form-send'></div>");
                $('#form-send').html("<span>Mensagem enviada!</span><p>Em breve eu entro em contato com você. Abraços.</p>")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                $('#form-send');
                });
            };
        },
        error: function(response) {
            $('.formphp').html("<div id='form-erro'></div>");
            $('#form-erro').html("<span>Falha no envio!</span><p>Você pode tentar novamente, ou enviar direto para o e-mail " + emailContato + " </p>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
            $('#form-erro');  
        });
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a documentação, você pode reiniciar a animação com o seguinte comando:

```
Pace.restart();
```

Basta inserir o código na função do evento que detecta o submit do formulário:

```
$('.formphp').on('submit', function() {
    Pace.restart(); // inicia a animação
...
```

O exemplo abaixo é apenas para ilustrar o funcionamento do comando:

```js
function anima(){
   Pace.restart();
}
```

```css
.pace {
-webkit-pointer-events: none;
pointer-events: none;

-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.pace-inactive {
display: none;
}
.pace .pace-progress {
background: #8BB006;
position: fixed;
z-index: 2000;
top: 0;
right: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" onclick="anima()" name="enviar" type="submit">Clique aqui</button>
```